# IMAP setting for hotmail in Outlook v14 for mac os x

Tags: imap, hotmail

I got for a few years a hotmail account and get my mail into outlook with POP setting.... everything is fine... But now i got a iPhone and iPad and there is some setting to get IMAP hotmail (m.hotmail.com) wich work fine for ipad and iphone, but NOT for outlook...

How to make outlook sync hotmail as IMAP ?

Answer (score 1):

The following settings (as provided here: [Windows Help](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app)) should work.
This works for me apart from one, ah, small glitch (compare here: [Question 76499](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110916/mac-mail-syncs-all-folders-except-inbox-when-connecting-through-imap)).

**Incoming (IMAP) Server**
Server address: imap-mail.outlook.com
Port: 993
Encrypted Connection: SSL

**Outgoing (SMTP) Server**
Server address: smtp-mail.outlook.com
Port: 25 (or 587 if 25 is blocked)
Authentication: Yes
Encrypted Connection: TLS