# Is there a plugin for hotmail calendars

Tags: calendar, hotmail

I'd like to see my hotmail calendars using iCal (or if need be, another calendar tool).

I have a new mac running Maverick and I'm blown away by the answers I'm seeing online. I don't want to forward my calendars to another email account like gmail. That's a ridiculous work around. It's 2014!

What are my other options? Is there some kind of plugin for acccount connections? or is there another program I can use to see my calendars instead of iCal? (keep it free people).

Thanks

Comment: Does http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76499/imap-setting-for-hotmail-in-outlook-v14-for-mac-os-x?rq=1 help?

Comment: No, mail is the one thing that actually works well with hotmail. Calendars, Contacts, Reminders, are all things that don't work with the native apple apps.

Comment: Is https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2298116?start=0&tstart=0 something you call forwarding?

Comment: @patrix yes that's what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Go into outlook (hotmail) calendar and push "share" then choose the option to send a View only Link.

Copy the "Import into other calendar applications (ICS)" link.

On your mac, go to Calendar and subscribe.

Write a name for your calendar and then enter the URL you copied from hotmail, substituting "http" for "webcals".

Chose how often you want it it to refresh, what alerts you want, then enter and the calendar from hotmail will appear on your Mac!

Comment: This doesn't allow me to write or edit though. It's a huge pain.

Comment: Step 1 now you can see it in iCal yes, no ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's half of the battle. Being able to add and edit events is a must.

Comment: OK, now lets try to set up sharing ! as co-owner !!